# How to show different Views with a single table section?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift3

i have a tableView, and at my indexpath.section 4 i have the "My Account" that when tapped it should show two different views depending on the situation, what i'm trying to do is:

1. when the user first comes to this part of the app, show the login view controller
2. if the user is logged in show the "Account View Controller" which holds user info if not then show the regular "Login View Controller"

Everything is connected with navigation controller to move between views, since i'm using the SWRevealVIewController to use a side menu or drawer menu

here is the code i'm trying to use

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.section)

    let isUserLoggedIn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")

    if indexPath.section == 4 {

        if isUserLoggedIn {

            let AccountVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AccountViewController") as! AccountViewController

            self.present(AccountVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }else{

            let LoginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginView") as! LoginViewController

            self.present(LoginVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

    }
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Whats your sign in mechanism? Usually you'd store some sort of token or so on the device (better not store passwords and usernames). You could store the token in your db/user defaults/realm/file or what ever your preferred data store is.

Check if a token is present and use a simple if to either perform this or that segue if you are using storyboard. If you are doing it programmatically just call present() or push() to show the appropriate screen.

Update: Sorry, I haven't looked at the code. It looks correct to me so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: main problem is that once the user logs in, the "login view controller" won't perform the segue to "Account view Controller"

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are no segues involved because you manually instantiate the view controller via storyboard and present it programmatically. If you want to use segues, you should call "performSegue(withIdentifier)" instead of instantiating the view controller and calling "present()"

Comment: now i got it working but the "account view" won't stay, meaning if the user goes to another section of the table view and comes back to "my account" then it goes back to "log in view"

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "account view" and "comes back". Sounds like you are returning wrong cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Or do you mean when the user comes back and tapps on the account cell it presents the wrong view controller again?

Comment: i'm sorry having a hard time trying to explain it, but here is my best shot... i have 2 views "loginView" and "AccountView" then on my table my section 4 of the table which is a label named "MyAccount", so what i'm trying to do is if the user isn't logged in show the "loginView" when "MyAccount" is tapped, but if the user is already logged in show "AccountView"...but right now if the user logs in and goes to another another section of the table and comes back to "MyAccount" then it shows "loginView" instead of "AccountView"